# log all SQLDataReader fields

Tags: c#, log4net

I am writing a classic SQL routine similar to this:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        log.Info("New record found");

    }
```

I am using log4net.

I wish to have the fields of the current record sent to a debug log.

I try this (noting that log4.net will serialize the object):

```
log.debug(reader);
```

I expect all fields and values to be logged.  Instead I get an error..

Comment: WHICH ERROR do you get?

Comment: can you show more code in regards to how you are executing the query also show us the error if you are not sure how to ask a question here please read the following [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: If you try to use log4net to serialize and log the reader object you will receive the error below.  

InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

The goal is when I have a record, I want to log all fields of that record to a log.  My initial approach was to use log4net to log the whole "reader" object as it will attempt to serialize it.

Comment: this is telling you what the error is .. perhaps you did not execute the query correctly using the `DataReader` once again this is a classic case of `Why doesn't my code work` when it's on your machine and we can't see what it is  you're looking at.. how do you expect someone to help when you posted so little code.. also `Use the Debugger` and do your do diligence on your end by pinpointing the issue first..

Comment: MethodMan, I have to disagree.  

The simple ask was "I wish to have the fields of the current record sent to a debug log."

It looks like the solution is to GetValues and then serialize that.

                log.Info("New record found");                
                Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
                int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);
                log.Debug(values);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call GetValues first then serialize response:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            log.Info("New record found");                
            Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
            int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);
            log.Debug(values);
         }
```